# Allocate a multidimensional array without recursion

Tags: c++, arrays

Suppose I have an arbitrary size array of integer values that specify the number of elements for each dimension (level) of the array to be allocated, how do I allocate the array without resorting to recursion? It's preferable to do it without recursion to avoid stack overflow.

So, for example, how to complete a function like this:

```
template <typename Type>
void* allocMulti (int numDim, int* numElementsPerDim)
{
    // 'Type' if one-dimensional, should be 'void*' otherwise
    void* multiArray = new Type[numElementsPerDim[0]];
    // ...
    return multiArray;
}
```

I'm looking for a *general algorithm* that would cover languages without direct memory access.

Comment: Multiply all dimensions then allocate an array of that size.

Comment: @RedX I'm looking for a general algorithm, an algorithm applicable in various languages, like PHP for instance.

Comment: If you multiply the dimensions, also multiply by `sizeof (int)`! This will work in any language, as long as you're willing to do your own array index arithmetic. If you want arrays of pointers, that's a different matter.

Comment: Take a look at boost http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks, but again, I'm after a general algorithm.

Comment: @DesmondHume, different languages and platforms will require different idioms. There is no "general algorithm".

Comment: @StoryTeller As long as the language can allocate an array and allows an element of an array to be of array type, there exists a similar algorithm for all such languages.

Comment: @DesmondHume, you are being terribly naive. To reinterpret a 1-D array as an N-D array in C++ will require template meta-programming. While it may be damn near impossible in others.

Comment: @DesmondHume, StoryTeller is right: different languages support different idioms. For example you can solve your problem in C++ using templates and macros, but those features aren't available in most other languages. Conversely a lot of the problems you're going to have implementing this in C/C++ stem from static typing and the fact that C doesn't really support multi-dimensional arrays - you're not going to have those issues in other languages.

RedX's suggestion is probably the most generic that will be applicable to the largest number of languages.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is actually a matrix (e.g. length AxB and not a list of arrays of different lengths), then you could allocate a single array of length A*B instead of an array of length A where each position is a pointer to an array of length B.

This could also improve performance, as the memory is continuous (less paging).

You would have to access each cells using a[y * B + x] instead of a[y][x] though (assuming dim(a,0) = A and dim(a,1) = B.

My C++ my be a bit rusty, however, I believe this sort of approach may work:

```
T* AllocateMatrix(int dims, int[] dimLengths)
{
    // Assert dims >= 1
    int length = dims[0];

    for (int d = 1; d < dims; d++)
        length *= dims[d];

    return new T[length];
}

*T AccessMatrix(T* matrix, int dims, int[] dimLengths, int[] pos)
{
    // Assert dims >= 1
    int p = pos[0];

    for (int d = 1; d < dims; d++)
    {
        p = p * dimLengths[d] + pos[d];
    }

    return &matrix[p];
}
```

Comment: That is a step in the correct the direction, but the question is how to reinterpret that chunck of memory without hardcoding the number of dimensions.

Comment: It's still a 1-D array, not a proper N-D array. Still a good answer, and probably as good as it can get in C.

Comment: @StoryTeller in C++ the N-D arrays aren't really matrices, but arrays of pointers, so a. it can't get any better, b. this is more efficient.

Comment: You are quite incorrect, since C++ inherits C's multi-dimensional arrays, and even applies them to classes.

Comment: @StoryTeller and in C a** is an array of pointers, not a long chunk of memory.

Comment: But `a[M][N]` is. Which is what the OP was asking about, unless I misunderstood him.

Comment: a[M][N] is an array of arrays, basically T**, which is why you need recursion to allocate it. In C# for instance there is a[][] vs. a[,] where a[][] is like C/C++ and a[,] is a matrix.

Comment: @DannyVarod, to say `T[M][N]` is the same as `T**` is just plain wrong. `T[M][N]` is a contigious block of memory. Implicit casting doesn't even compile with C++'s stricter type checking. http://ideone.com/QaJ2B3

Comment: @DesmondHume I know this isn't exactly what you asked, but it is a possible workaround for the problem you provided.

Comment: @StoryTeller my mistake. My C++ must be rustier than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach: Allocate the data values as a block, then all the rows of `(int *)` as a block, then the rows of `(int **)` as a block, etc.

a) Allocate all the data values as a block. If you have `nDim` dimensions in the array `elementsPerDim`, there are `prod = product(elementsPerDim, nDim)` data values (which you can easily calculate), so you need to allocate:

```
int prod = product(elementsPerDim, nDim);
int * intblock = calloc(prod, sizeof(int));
```

b) Allocate all the `(int*)`. Their number is equal to the product of all the dimensions except the last one, so you can simply call your `product()` function with length `nDim-1`. So there are `product(elementsPerDim, nDim-1)` such values, each of size `sizeof (int*)`. Let's allocate them:

```
int npointers = product(elementsPerDim, nDim-1);
int ** ptrblock = calloc(npointers, sizeof (int *));
```

Now you must initialize them to point into your block from the previous step. Each pointer gets a non-overlapping block of `elementsPerDim[nDim-2]` ints, like this:

```
int rowlength = elementsPerDim[nDim-2];
for (int i=0; i < npointers; i++)
    ptrblock[i] = & intblock[i * rowlength];   /* a.k.a. intblock + i*rowlength */
```

c) Iterate step b backwards until you run out of dimensions. I.e., follow up step (b) with this loop:

```
void ** prev_block = (void **) ptrblock;
void ** curblock;

for (int d = nDim-2; d > 0; d--) {
    int npointers = product(elementsPerDim, d);
    curblock = calloc(npointers, sizeof (void **));

    int rowlength = elementsPerDim[d-1];
    for (int i=0; i < npointers; i++)
        curblock[i] = & prev_block[i * rowlength];

    prev_block = curblock;  /* get ready for the next round */
}
```

When you're done, `curblock` will be an array of pointers pointing into the block of second-level pointers, and so on down to the block of ints. You can use normal array notation to dereference them:
  `ptrblock[3][2][15]`, etc.

I may have gotten an index off by one somewhere, but this should be the algorithm. You'll notice this is in C, and uses `void **` instead of stacking the number of dereferences. You did say you were interested in the algorithm, not in type golf... (It should work as long as all pointers have the same size on your machine.)